# Create unique pair based on the giving array

Tags: algorithm

I was unable to solve this question. Looking for the help of algo expert.
It will be great if the solution is provided in javascript, but it does not matter.

Given input:

```
[
 [1,2,3]
 [4,5,6]
 [7,8]
 ...
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
 [1,4,7]
 [1,4,8]
 [1,5,7]
 [1,5,8]
 [1,6,7]
 [1,6,8]
 [2,4,7]
 [2,4,8]
 [2,5,7]
 [2,5,8]
 [2,6,7]
 [2,6,8]
 [3,4,7]
 [3,4,8]
 [3,5,7]
 [3,5,8]
 [3,6,7]
 [3,6,8]
]
```

Comment: Just use 3 nested loops. No algo expert is needed here.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Note the `...` in the input description. How many nested loop do you need to handle those?

Comment: I focused mainly on the result. A recursion should do the thing.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Nikolas was commented on the question before I edited it. My bad, I did not state my question clearly earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function. Here I have chosen to implement it as a generator, using `*` and `yield`. The caller can either iterate the function's result directly with a `for` loop, or turn it into an array:

```js
function * generateCombis(data) {
    if (data.length === 0) return yield [];
    let [arr, ...rest] = data;
    for (let val of arr) {
        for (let combi of generateCombis(rest)) {
            yield [val, ...combi];
        }
    }
}

let data = [
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8]
];

let result = Array.from(generateCombis(data));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Salute to you, for the quick and clear answer. I have no knowledge about generator, seem powerful and thanks for intro it to me.